# proving improper integral converge

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm trying to prove the following integral converge:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}-1}{x^\frac{2}{3}}
$$
since 0 and $\infty$ are the problematic points I've done this:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}-1}{x^\frac{2}{3}} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}-1}{x^\frac{2}{3}} + \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}-1}{x^\frac{2}{3}}
$$

now I know: 
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}-1}{x^\frac{2}{3}} \leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^\frac{2}{3}} < \infty$$
because: 
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^\alpha } < \infty \iff \alpha <1$$

Now, I'm just having difficulties proving the other part converges, any help is appreciated!

Comment: A substitution, $u = 1/x$, could help.

Comment: I've tried that but not with much luck. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: Also, $1-e^{-1/x} = \frac1x e^t \le \frac1x$ for some $t\in[-\frac1x,1]$ by the mean value theorem; thus the second integral is bounded above by $\int_1^\infty x^{-5/3}\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Change variables: $y=1/x$, $dx/x=-dy/y$. Then the integral becomes
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-y}-1}{y^{4/3}} \, dy. $$
Split at $y=1$, and then
$$ \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{-y}}{y^{4/3}} \, dy $$
is bounded by $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{dy}{y^{4/3}}$, which converges. Meanwhile, on $[0,1]$ we have
$$ \frac{e-1}{e}y \leqslant 1-e^{-y} \leqslant y $$
(draw a picture, look at the tangent at $0$ and the secant through $0$ and $1$), so the integral over $[0,1]$ is bounded by a multiple of
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{y}{y^{4/3}} \, dy = \int_0^1 \frac{dy}{y^{1/3}}, $$
which converges.